# Augmenting the Cost Function with a Gaussian Prior

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, rnn

I'm doing an online course and one of the assignment says:

> To avoid parameters from exploding or becoming highly correlated, it is helpful to augment
>   our cost function with a Gaussian prior: this tends to push parameter weights closer to zero, without
>   constraining their direction, and often leads to classifiers with better generalization ability.

Exactly what does "augment our cost function with a Gaussian prior" mean, and how could I go about doing that?

I tried searching on google but didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Welcome to DataScience.SE! You should read about the [bias-variance trade-off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff) and [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the example of linear regression. Instead of deriving it from solving the normal equations, we can motivate it by thinking about it as finding the conditional distribution $P(y|x)$. Let's assume that this distribution follows a Gaussian distribution with fixed variance $\sigma^2$ and mean $\hat{y}(x,w)$ and weights $w$. Assuming that samples are i.i.d. we can easily show that applying maximum-likelihood gives the same values of $w$ than minimizing the mean squared error. See [example 5.5.1](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html) for a mathematical explanation.

If we additionally assume a prior Gaussian distribution for $P(w)$ (w.l.o.g. we can assume unit variance $I$), we can now show that the posterior $P(w | x,y)$  of $w$ is also Gaussian distributed (that is because the prior is "conjugate") with variance $\frac{1}{\alpha} I$ and we recover linear regression with weight decay $\alpha w^T w=\alpha \lVert w \rVert^2_2$  (i.e. [$L^2$ or Tikhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization)).

Intuitively, a Gaussian distribution's probability mass is centered around the mean (assumed here to be zero). If we assume such a distribution for the coefficients in the linear regression (as our prior knowledge), linear regression will favor coefficients close to zero.

All of this is nicely explained [here (chapter 5)](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html) or [here (chapter 18)](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/textbook/181115.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

It was hard to look for anything based on the information. Still, I found this interesting paper- [Augmented Functional Time Series Representation and Forecasting with Gaussian Processes](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3324-augmented-functional-time-series-representation-and-forecasting-with-gaussian-processes.pdf) on the web.

Just explore it. Hope it will help you upto some extent. Cheers!